# How can I ignore failures to decrypt a vaulted file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have two roles, one of which has a `group_vars` file that is vaulted, and another that is not. I would like to run the role that does not require any vaulted information, but ansible prompts me for a vault password anyway:

```
$ tree
├── deploy-home-secure.yml
├── deploy-home.yml
├── group_vars
│   ├── home
│   │   └── unvaulted
│   └── home-secure
│       ├── unvaulted
│       └── vaulted
├── hosts
└── roles
    ├── home
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yaml
    └── home-secure
        └── tasks
            └── main.yaml

$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 1.8.2
  configured module search path = None

$ ansible-playbook -i hosts deploy-home.yml
ERROR: A vault password must be specified to decrypt vaulttest/group_vars/home-secure/vaulted

$ ansible-playbook --vault-password-file=/dev/null -i hosts deploy-home.yml
ERROR: Decryption failed
```

Comment: I suspect Ansible needs to read everything in `group_vars` to make sure it doesn't miss anything. If that's the case, then why not move your encrypted playbooks into a separate _"secure"_ directory?

Comment: @Mxx "to make sure it doesn't miss anything" - I would have hoped that the normal undefined variable warning would have kicked in - if we can't decrypt, then those variables wouldn't be available.

Comment: @Mxx "move your encrypted playbooks" - I'm not sure I follow. It is `group_vars` files that are vaulted, and those have to be in a structure relative to the `hosts` file, as I understand it. I wouldn't want to have to duplicate my hosts file for each vaulted file with a different password.

Comment: Your inventory file is not linked to your playbooks in any way(other than referenced hosts inside the playbooks). So you could have a central location for your inventory and separate locations for each playbook.

Comment: @Mxx I must be vastly misunderstanding something here. The file `group_vars/home_secure/vaulted` is the file that has been vaulted. I understand that ["group variables are generally placed alongside your inventory file"](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). I expect to need a password to run the `home_secure` role, but not for the `home` role. I don't see how moving my playbook (`deploy-home.yml`) would make Ansible not load the vaulted `group_vars` file.

Comment: Separate everything related to encrypted playbook from unencrypted one. You can still have a common inventory file.

Comment: Shepmaster, if the answer answers your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 12):

I have something like this to solve this kind of problem (mine was not different roles, but different hosts, but I think the same principle applies):

This is the simplified file structure:

```
group_vars
  development_vars
  staging_vars 
vaulted_vars
  production_vars
```

This allows you to deploy development or staging without Ansible asking you to decrypt production_vars.

And then, the production playbook goes like this:

```
hosts: production
roles:
  - role...
vars_files:
  - vaulted_vars/production_vars
```

The vars_files line where you specify the path to the vaulted var is the key.

Answer (score 7):

Ansible will try to load a group_vars file for any group it encounters in your inventory. If you split inventory file (hosts) into one for home group and another for home-secure then it will not try to decrypt vars it is not supposed to.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts-home deploy-home.yml

$ ansible-playbook --ask-vault-password -i hosts-home-secure deploy-home-secure.yml
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option if you don't always need your vaulted variables.

You can have a folder structure like this:

```
group_vars
├── all
├── prod
├── dev
│   └── vars.yml
└── dev-vault
    └── vault.yml
```

You store vaulted variables in the '-vault' variant of that inventory.

Then your inventories might be something like the following:

dev:

```
[servers]
dev.bla.bla


[dev:children]
servers
```

dev-vault:

```
[servers]
dev.bla.bla


[dev:children]
servers

[dev-vault:children]
servers
```

So you're only saving sensitive data in the dev-vault vars, if in most cases you don't actually need passwords etc you can run playbooks without having extra options you're not really using, or storing the vault password in plaintext for convenience, etc.

So the "normal" command might be:

```
 ansible-playbook -i dev some.yml
```

And the "vaulted" command could be:

```
 ansible-playbook -i dev-vault some.yml --extra-vars="use_vault=true"
```

Or you could manage the "include vault variables" via tagging, including some.yml in some-vault.yml etc

Answer (score 0):

Hack ansible.

So... the file in question is `{your-python-lib-location}/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py`

Somewhere near line 750, you will find this block:

```
    else:
        msg = "Decryption failed (no vault secrets were found that could decrypt)"
        if filename:
            msg += " on %s" % to_native(filename)
        raise AnsibleVaultError(msg)

    if b_plaintext is None:
        msg = "Decryption failed"
        if filename:
            msg += " on %s" % to_native(filename)
        raise AnsibleError(msg)
        
    return b_plaintext, vault_id_used, vault_secret_used
```

Replace that with:

```
    else:
        msg = "Decryption failed (no vault secrets were found that could decrypt)"
        if filename:
            msg += " on %s" % to_native(filename)
        display.warning(msg, formatted=True)
        
    if b_plaintext is None:
        msg = "Decryption failed"
        if filename:
            msg += " on %s" % to_native(filename)
        display.warning(msg, formatted=True)
        b_plaintext = []

    return b_plaintext, vault_id_used, vault_secret_used
```

So, you're changing `raise` to `display.warning` and setting `b_plaintext` to an empty dictionary.